# Excel or Google formula to count occurrences of an 8-digit number within a text string

Tags: regex, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I hope that you can help me.

I have a data set which includes a free text comments field; within that field there are work order numbers entered which I want to count - the WO numbers are ALWAYS 8 digits long and I thought that I had cracked it with this:
`=ROUNDDOWN(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(M7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M7, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"")))/8,0)` which correctly identifies the WO numbers in a comment like this:

```
NWMS - 67431710 - Mattress eta pending from contractor
NWMS - 67431797 - Double base eta pending from contractor
```

and returns a count of 2 (that's a single cell with multi-line comments).

Also; because of the `ROUNDDOWN` formula; a comment like this:
`CMS - 67630485 smell  From waste outlets or blockage eta 05.02` only returns a count of 1 WO (which is correct)

However; the new problem I am facing is when an ETA date is added which also has 8 digits - e.g. 07/02/2020 - this incorrectly adds 1 to the WO number count.

I guess that I'm after a way of counting blocks of 8 contiguous numbers in a larger text string. This will exclude any other digits however they are entered.

I'm working in Google Sheets but I understand Excel better so a formula for either will help me as I should be able to convert it either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked about using Regular Expressions in Excel, here is simple UDF which will return a `Count` of `Pattern` in `String`.

It should be portable to other versions of Windows Excel.
It will not work on Mac Excel as that does not have the required dll

```
Option Explicit
Function REGEXCount(S As String, sPattern As String) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPattern
    Set MC = .Execute(S)
End With

REGEXCount = MC.Count
End Function
```

You can use this on your worksheet like:

```
=REGEXCount(cell_ref or string,"\b\d{8}\b")
```

The assumption is that your eight digits are surrounded by a non-word character or the beginning or end of the line/string.

Word characters are anything in the set of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

If the WO might be preceded or followed by an underscore, then just change the pattern to: `(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]|^)\d{8}(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]|$)`

The UDF could be made more flexible, but this will work for your example.

[image]

Comment: thanks @Ron that works a treat - the 1st pattern you quoted also counts WO numbers preceded or followed by a dash too. I'm not sure if I can distribute a Macro-enabled excel file within our organisation but your answer does work!! thanks again

Comment: @AlanEnglefield Yes, both will do that since a dash or hyphen is a non-word character. Is that what you want?  or not?  If not, please provide examples of data and your expected outcome.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted. Basically I need to extract the **number** of work orders hidden in amongst all of the comments and ETAs however they appear (and given that it is a free text field; they are usually surrounded by a load of guff that I don't need haha) thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You could try using regular expressions (in Google Sheets) to match an eight-digit number.

For example, the following will replace all groups of eight-digit numbers with `@`.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(M7,"\d{8}","@")
```

And then you could use the `len(M7) - len(substitute(...` method to count the number of occurrences of eight-digit numbers in the string.

The final formula would look something like

```
=len(REGEXREPLACE(M7,"\d{8}","@"))-len(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(M7,"\d{8}","@"),"@",""))
```

Comment: This looks great; I guess the main difference between REGEXREPLACE and SUBSTITUTE is that you can search for blocks ({8}) rather than just a single digit which is exactly what I needed. Out of interest, is there an Excel equivalent?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't really use Excel anymore. So if a new formula was recently introduced, I wouldn't know. :-)

Comment: @AlanEnglefield You'd have to write a UDF in VBA to be able to use Regex expressions on the worksheet.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Is that something you can advise on? Also; would it go with the file if I emailed it to someone else? Thanks

Comment: @AlanEnglefield Look at the accepted answer for [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops). So far as distributing it, you'd probably want to change the recommendation from early binding to late binding, so your users won't have to tick the reference.

Answer (score 3):

In MS Excel you can use `FILTERXML` function to get necessary result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FILTERXML("<data><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>") & "</a></data>","//a"))*(LEN(FILTERXML("<data><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>") & "</a></data>","//a"))=8))
```

Only spaces should be without duplication.

[image]

**Edit #1:**

Solution for leading zeros and duplicate spaces:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FILTERXML("<data><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>") & "</a></data>","//a"))*(LEN(FILTERXML("<data><a>#" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>#") & "</a></data>","//a"))=9))
```

**Edit #2:**

Solution to exclude time too:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FILTERXML("<data><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A5,":","_")," ","</a><a>") & "</a></data>","//a"))*(LEN(FILTERXML("<data><a>#" & SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","</a><a>#") & "</a></data>","//a"))=9))
```

Comment: Because of the way `FILTERXML` handles numeric data, this method will return unreliable results if the **WO** numbers have leading zero's.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfield Yes, but it can be easily solved. Edited.

Comment: @basic This is brilliant - thanks however; I've used your edited example on the following and I get a count of 2?? 'mde - 67832405 New Temporary Barrel Required - lock seized,cant access room -  09-Feb-2020 08:55:43' is it because of the time element?

Comment: Yes, it's because of the time element. Well, we can add another replacement - replace ":" with "_" in the ISNUMBER test. Edited.

Comment: Thanks @basicbut unfortunately; your formulas miss any work order numbers which have dashes attached. As far as I understand your formulae, they are looking for a block of 8 digits **surrounded by spaces** but, as this is fed by a free text field, that is not always the case :o(

Answer (score 0):

shorter Google Sheets alternative:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\d{8}", "♦♥"), "♦"), "*♥*"))
```

[image: 0]